# Where to hold important lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My app has numerous lists of options that, for example, govern which stage a project is at - these are options users choose from a `select` list. I have many of these and I'm running into an organization problem, namely where to define these in one place so the system stays DRY.

I'm also wary of generating lots of polymorphic tables in the interests of normalization, which sometimes complicate the code quite a bit without adding too much in the way of real value.

Can you give me an example of where to store some options that are 1) the only options possible for a field, and 2) available in any form system-wide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the `symbolize` gem for that kind of scenario. You can store field options as strings, perform operations on the model values as symbols, use i18n for labels, and there's even a set of helpers to build `select`s based on the options.

Also, the code is kept very clean, since you set the available options on the model itself.

Check it out:

https://github.com/nofxx/symbolize

Here's a sample from their documentation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  symbolize :gender, :in => [:female, :male], :scopes => true
  symbolize :so, :in => {
    :linux   => "Linux",
    :mac     => "Mac OS X"
  }, :scopes => true

  # Allow blank
  symbolize :gui,  :in => [:gnome, :kde, :xfce], :allow_blank => true

  # Don`t i18n
  symbolize :browser, :in => [:firefox, :opera], :i18n => false, :methods => true

  # Scopes
  symbolize :angry, :in => [true, false], :scopes => true

  # Don`t validate
  symbolize :lang, :in => [:ruby, :c, :erlang], :validate => false

  # Default
  symbolize :kind, :in => [:admin, :manager, :user], :default => :admin
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since ActiveRecord does not support `ENUM` or `SET` attributes, that would fit perfectly wit what you need, database-side, I think the best possible way is to store this data in a constant, put in an initializer (e.g. `conf/initializers/constants.rb`). In this way you can both use them to construct your `<select>` tags and in a model (for example with a `validates :field, :inclusion => ALLOWED_VALUES`). If you stored the constant in the application controller you wouldn't be able to access it in your models.

Answer (score 0):

Would storing an array of constants in your applicationcontroller solve your problem?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    OPTIONS = ["option1", "option2", "etc"]
end
```